# How can I open an App from Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, javascript, application-launch

After downloading a kindle book, I can open Kindle for Mac app by clicking a button. How can I do some similar things? I mean, how can I open an app from Safari?

Comment: See [How can I run a script from within a web browser?](http://superuser.com/questions/202831/how-can-i-run-a-script-from-within-a-web-browser)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but in safari, if you've downloaded a document or app, you can click that document or app in the Downloads window and it will open it.