# How can I run a script from within a web browser?

Tags: browser, script

I would like to be able to use a web browser to launch applescripts or quickies shortcuts.
The problem is in Safari, for instance, a link to a script just shows it in the Finder.
It will not run a script. I know this is because of security issues, but is there a way to make a browser open these scripts?

Is there a browser that will do it? This use to work fine using an old version of Internet Explorer for Mac, but since upgrading to Snow Leopard, I can't get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to automate tasks **in** your web browser? Then iMacros for [Firefox](http://www.iopus.com/de/imacros/firefox/) and iMacros for [Chrome](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/chrome/) is what you need. These two are free/open-source ["web browser macro recorder](http://wiki.imacros.net/Main_Page)" addons.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. He doesn't want to record.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own AppleScript *application*, which allows you to also [register your own URL schemes](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/), such as `myapp:`. When such AppleScript application is then installed on some Mac, it will "listen" to URLs you defined, like `myapp://go?text=Hello%20world`. Clicking such URL will run the AppleScript right away.

See [How do I make Safari open search results in a new tab by default?](https://superuser.com/questions/204435/how-do-i-make-safari-open-search-results-in-a-new-tab-by-default/205510#205510) for an example.

AppleScript also supports the `applescript:` URL scheme. However: that will *not* run the script, but only open it in AppleScript Editor, after which you need to run it yourself. Like copy the following (as one line) into any browser on Mac OS X:

> applescript://com.apple.scripteditor?action=new&script=display%20dialog%20%22Hello%2C%20World%21%22

To convert a script into such a clickable `applescript:` URL, see [Convert Script to Markup Code](http://www.jonn8.com/html/Convert_Script_to_MC.html).

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer 8, you can enable the running of Java applets by clicking TOOLS > INTERNET OPTIONS > SECURITY > LOCAL INTRANET > CUSTOM LEVEL and then set ENABLE for the option 'Scripting of Java applets' in the SCRIPTING section.

That section controls all scripting settings on your local intranet, including your local hard disk.

Because you are adjusting only the LOCAL INTRANET zone, this does not risk a security breach. Scripting in the INTERNET zone, for instance, is not affected by changes made only in the LOCAL INTRANET zone.