# How do I make Safari open search results in a new tab by default?

Tags: macos, search, safari

I'd like for results from the search toolbar to open in a new tab by default, like I've configured in Firefox.  How can I get this same default behavior in Safari?  I already know that Command-Enter will do this for me, but I want to change the default behavior so that I don't have to hold down Command every time I do a search.

Comment: Not an answer, but I wonder how you get the cursor into the search field to start with. If you use your mouse or touchpad, then maybe the following makes your workflow a bit easier: Command-N for a new window, followed by Tab to get into the search field, and after typing your search text: Return to show the search results in that (new) window.

Comment: @Arjan: Can be slow on some machines, because it might load the Top Sites for new windows. Cmd-L for Location bar, Tab, Search, Cmd-Enter is faster (at least on my machine and in my opinion).

Comment: @Arjan Glims can be configured to focus the search field for new windows and tabs. Saves a keystroke.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I just checked [Saft](http://www.pimpmysafari.com/plugins/saft) (well-known commercial Safari modification), [Glims](http://www.machangout.com/) and the Safari Extensions library, nothing turned up. It seems you need to continue using Firefox for full customizability.

Comment: Wow, that's horrible.   -1 to Safari.

Comment: `Secrets.prefPane`, a utility that can change "hidden" application settings, also doesn't list anything in that regard.

Comment: @Jeff You could try to write the Glims folks with your suggestion, maybe they add that for a future version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in to some work, then Glims with a custom search provider, and some AppleScript to create your own protocol handler (URL scheme) can do the trick. But I think pressing Command-Return is *much* easier. ;-)

Here's what you'd need:

1. Open Applications, AppleScript Editor, and paste the following:

   ```
    -- See http://superuser.com/questions/204435/
    on open location fullUrl
      -- fullUrl includes the URL scheme, like "newwindow:" or "newwindow://"
      set a to the offset of ":" in fullUrl
      set b to the offset of "//" in fullUrl
      if b = a + 1 then set a to a + 2
      set theUrl to text from (a + 1) to -1 of fullUrl
      -- Delegate the new URL to whatever is the default handler:
      tell application "System Events"
        open location theUrl
      end tell
    end open location

    -- Just in case this is invoked directly from Finder:
    set choice to button returned of (display dialog "Please use a URL like
        newwindow://http://google.com
    to use this." buttons {"More info...", "Cancel"})
    if choice = "More info..." then
      tell application "System Events"
        open location "http://superuser.com/questions/204435/"
      end tell
    end if
   ```
2. Select menu File, Save As, and be sure to select File Format: "Application". This will create something that looks like a single application, but actually holds a folder structure.
3. In Finder, find the place where you saved the application, right-click it and select "Show package contents".
4. Find file `Contents/FileInfo.plist` and open it with a text editor.
5. At the end, just above the last two lines `</dict></plist>`, add:

   ```
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.superuser.204435.NewWindow</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>NewWindow</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>newwindow</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
   ```
6. Move the whole application package into, for example, Application/Utilities (to ensure Launch Services [registers it](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-BABEJFCD)).
7. Test in any browser, using `newwindow://http://www.google.com/search?q=abc`. If it doesn't work, then double-click the application or even rename the package, just to trigger the discovery by Launch Services again.
8. Install the [Glims](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims) plugin for Safari.
9. In Safari's preferences, tab sheet Glims, Search Engine List, add a new entry. Note that Glims requires the slashes after `newwindow:`. Without that, Glims would prefix `http://` to whatever text you entered:

   ```
    newwindow://http://google.com/search?q=#query#
   ```

I don't know how to change the icon that Glims shows... Also, when using this, there's no key you can hold down to *not* open the results in a new window.

Comment: ...and to open in a new Tab: set Safari to use tabs when a new window is opened. Did I mention that Command-Return is *soooo* much easier? ;-)

Comment: Yikes!  I think I'll stick with Command-Return for now.

Comment: And generally I guess I'll use Chrome and Firefox instead of Safari.

Comment: Wow. This is... insane. Wow. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I found out so far:

- It is not possible in vanilla Safari
- It is not added in [Saft](https://web.archive.org/web/20110216063446/http://www.pimpmysafari.com/plugins/saft) (well-known commercial Safari modification)
- It is not added in [Glims](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims).
- There is no Safari extension for that and the [Safari API](https://developer.apple.com/safari/resources/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) does not support this for an extension.

Therefore, I don't think it's possible. It seems you need to continue using Firefox for full customizability.

Comment: Hmmm, now the homepage shows this question has an answer...

Comment: @Arjan what do you mean?

Comment: I mean this does not answer the question. But now this question no longer has zero answers, and hence might not trigger others to read it?

Answer (score 0):

Jeff wrote:

> ...I wonder how you get the cursor into the search field to start with...

You can do that with **Command-k** just as you would with Firefox. Just go into *Apple -> Preferences -> Keyboard* and add a new keyboard shortcut for Safari.

Comment: Jeff didn't write that, Arjan did. Furthermore, Command-Option-F is the shortcut to directly focus the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

Be default, here is how I do it:

1. With Safari open, press CMD + OPTION + F (puts cursor in search field)
2. enter my search term
3. press CMD + ENTER (opens results in a new tab)
4. Done, search results open in a new tab in 4 seconds or less

That said, I have updated CMD + OPTION + F to be CMD + K to match Firefox (and I think Chrome?)… but I would prefer that there was a checkbox in Safari Preferences on the "Tabs" tab to make search results open in a new tab.

Comment: Note: To customize the Safari search shortcut you have to:

Comment: … you have to do what?